# Transfer CSV files from azure blob storage to azure SQL database using azure data factory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I need to transfer around 20 CSV files inside a folder named ActivityPointer in an azure blob storage container to Azure SQL database in a single data factory pipeline, but ActivityPointer contains 20 CSV files and another folder named snapshots inside it. So when I try to create a pipeline and give * to select all the CSV files inside ActivityPointer it includes the snapshots folder too, which should not be included. Is there any possibilities to complete this task. Also I can't create another folder to transform the snapshots folder into it. What can I do now? Anyone can please help me out.

Comment: Sorry as per the client agreement I can't even share the screenshots of the data. 
I'm copying all the files to a same table. To answer your question you imagine there is a folder with several files and another sub folder but I want to copy only the data in those files and I shouldn't include the sub folder. What can I do?

Comment: Look at the answer given below. It should help achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to copy all CSV files within ACtivityPointer folder,
You can use wildcard expression as below :

[image]

you can provide path till Active folder and than *.csv

Answer (score 0):

Copy data is also considering the inner folder while using wildcards (even if we use `.csv` in wildcard file path). So, we have to validate whether it is a file or folder. Please look at the following demonstration.

- First use `Get Metadata` on the required folder with field list as `Child items`. The debug output will be:

[image]

- Now use this to iterate through child items using `For each` activity.

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
```

[image]

- Inside for each, use `if condition` activity to check whether the current item is a file or not. Use the following condition.

```
@equals(item().type,'File')
```

[image]

- When this is true, you can use `copy data` to complete copying the file to target table (Ignore the false case). I have create `file_name` parameter in my source dataset passing its value as `@item().name()`.

[image]

- This will help you to achieve your requirement. The following is the debug output. I have 4 files and 1 folder. The folder will be ignored, and the rest will be copied into the target table.

[image]